# Spinner inside TableCell not updating value

Tags: javafx

I've created a simple TableView that is fed with data from a database, and what I want is just to be able to easily change the value of a numeric column of that table with JavaFx.

But... since I have some mental issue or something, I can't make it work.

Below it's the "SpinnerCell" component, and the issue I've been having is that even after the commitEdit is fired, when I get the items from the TableView, no values were altered. What am I missing from this update lifecycle?

```
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

public class SpinnerTableCell<S, T extends Number> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    private final Spinner<T> spinner;

    public SpinnerTableCell() {
        this(1);
    }

    public SpinnerTableCell(int step) {
        this.spinner = new Spinner<>(0, 100, step);
        this.spinner.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> commitEdit(newValue));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T c, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(c, empty);

        if (empty || c == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
            return;
        }

        this.spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(c);

        setGraphic(spinner);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your table cell is always showing the editing control (the `Spinner`), you bypass the usual table cell mechanism for beginning an edit. For example, in the `TextFieldTableCell`, if the cell is not in an editing state, then a label is shown. When the user double-clicks the cell, it enters an editing state: the cell's `editingProperty()` is set to `true`, and the enclosing `TableView`'s `editingCellProperty()` is set to the position of the current cell, etc.

In your case, since this never happens, `isEditing()` is always `false` for the cell, and as a consequence, `commitEdit()` becomes a no-op.

Note that the `CheckBoxTableCell` is implemented similarly: its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html) highlights this fact. (The check box table cell implements its own direct update of properties via the `selectedStateCallback`.)

So there are two options here: one would be to enter an editing state when the spinner gains focus. You can do this by adding the following to the cell's constructor:

```
this.spinner.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
    if (isNowFocused) {
        getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
    }
});
```

Another option would be to provide a callback for "direct updates". So you could do something like:

```
public SpinnerTableCell(BiConsumer<S,T> update, int step) {
    this.spinner = new Spinner<>(0, 100, step);

    this.spinner.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        update.accept(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()), newValue));
}
```

and then given a model class for the table, say

```
public class Item {
    private int value ;
    public int getValue() { return value ;}
    public void setValue(int value) { this.value = value ;}

    // ...
}
```

You could do

```
TableView<Item> table = ... ;
TableColumn<Item, Integer> valueCol = new TableColumn<>("Value");
valueCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getValue()).asObject());
valueCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new SpinnerTableCell<>(Item::setValue, 1));
```

Comment: I wish to use the first approach, but it's causing bugs, now the spinner value does nothing when you click increment/decrement button.

Comment: Well, the second one worked like a charm. Thanks a LOT for your help. Sorry for making you answer such simple questions.

Comment: @MBarni Oh, this was an interesting one :). The first approach worked fine for me; sounds like maybe you got in some infinite loop via a `onEditCommit` handler, or something...?