# How to set a CellFactory with access to two specific fields

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have two variables inside a class: the amount and the maximum possible value for that amount.

I need a TableCell capable of receiving any number, as long as it doesn't surpass the maximum value present in each item.
I also need both values for other stuff, such as implementing a custom StringConverter, a custom TextField, etc.

However, I can't access the item value inside setCellFactory() !!!

Here it is more or less what I have done:

```
public class Item {
    
    private SimpleIntegerProperty amount;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty max; // maximum
    
    Item(int max,int amount){
        this.max = new SimpleIntegerProperty(max);
        this.amount = new SimpleIntegerProperty(amount);
    }
    
    
    public static TableView<Item> getTable(){
        TableColumn<Item,Number> colAmnt = new TableColumn<Item, Number>("column");
        colAmnt.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().amount); // I CAN access the item object (c.getValue()) here!
        colAmnt.setCellFactory(d->{
            // But I can't access it from here!!!
            return new MaxNumberTableCell();
        });
        
        // unimportant stuff
        colAmnt.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Item, Number> t) -> {
            Item o = ((Item) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow()));
            o.amount.setValue(t.getNewValue().intValue());
        });
        
        TableView<Item> t = new TableView<Item>();
        t.getColumns().add(colAmnt);
        t.setEditable(true);
        return t;
    }
    public int getMax() {
        return max.get();
    }
}
```

I have tried to get the value by extending TableCell<S,T> class as shown below, but I receive NullPointerException.

```
class MaxNumberTableCell extends TableCell<Item,Number>{
    public MaxNumberTableCell(){
        super();
        // Can't access from here either
        int a = this.getTableRow().getItem().getMax(); // NullPointerException
        // tldr: I need the value of a !
    }
}
```

**Edit**: If you want a minimal work example, here is the Main

```
public class Main extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Item> t = Item.getTable();
        ObservableList<Item> ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ol.add(new Item(5,1));
        t.setItems(ol);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(t);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please.. and do not use static scope

Comment: as to your first problem: most probably, you meed some further understanding of java language basics, in particular scoping/access rules. As to your second problem: what you are trying is utterly wrong - work through a tutorial on how to use TableView, in particular on how to implement custom cells (note: they are re-used during their lifetime!)

Comment: @kleopatra I posted the Main class so you can reproduce if you want. I don't understand what my "two problems" are. I have only one: I need to access max from inside TableCell

Comment: please read my comments thoroughly (you fixed only the first part of my first comment, thanks. Three more parts to go :)

Comment: @kleopatra Once again, I failed to visualize what are you talking about, I have an working solution and I didn't have "3 other parts to fix". You could answer so I could understand better

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're building an editable [property sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D%20property%20sheet) using `TableView`. As each `Item` in the model may have different bounds, you need access to the item's `max` attribute while editing in the `TableCell`. Your current [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71486405/230513) seems awkward, duplicating existing properties in the model. Instead, [*aggregate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) the value with its bounds as a `BoundedValue` and let the model contain a corresponding property:

```
private final ObjectProperty<BoundedValue> quantity;
```

In the example below, the amount and fraction columns each have the same cell value factory: `quantityProperty()`. In contrast, each column has a custom cell factory that displays the aspect of interest: an editable amount or a non-editable fraction displayed as a percentage. In either case, the factory's `TableCell` has access to any needed fields of the `BoundedValue`.

Going forward, you'll want to handle any `NumberFormatException` thrown by `Integer.valueOf()` or consider a `TextFormatter`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201446/230513). Related examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367255/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77995976/230513) illustrate using color to highlight cell state, and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703547/230513) examines using a `Spinner` as a `TableCell`.

[image]

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542867/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45200797/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41702771/230513
 */
public class BoundedValueTest extends Application {

    private static class BoundedValue {

        private final Integer value;
        private final Integer min;
        private final Integer max;

        public BoundedValue(int value, int min, int max) {
            if (value < min || value > max) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value out of bounds.");
            }
            this.value = value;
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
    }

    private static class Item {

        private final ObjectProperty<BoundedValue> quantity;

        Item(int quantity, int min, int max) {
            this.quantity = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(
                new BoundedValue(quantity, min, max));
        }

        private ObjectProperty<BoundedValue> quantityProperty() {
            return quantity;
        }
    }

    private TableCell<Item, BoundedValue> createQuantityCell() {
        TextFieldTableCell<Item, BoundedValue> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>();
        cell.setConverter(new StringConverter<BoundedValue>() {
            @Override
            public BoundedValue fromString(String string) {
                int min = cell.getItem().min;
                int max = cell.getItem().max;
                //TODO NumberFormatException vs TextFormatter  
                int value = Integer.valueOf(string);
                if (value < min || value > max) {
                    return cell.getItem();
                } else {
                    return new BoundedValue(value, min, max);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(BoundedValue item) {
                return item == null ? "" : item.value.toString();
            }
        });
        return cell;
    }

    private TableCell<Item, BoundedValue> createFractionCell() {
        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        TextFieldTableCell<Item, BoundedValue> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>(
            new StringConverter<BoundedValue>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(BoundedValue t) {
                return f.format((double) t.value / t.max);
            }

            @Override
            public BoundedValue fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        });
        return cell;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<Item> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(new Item(i, 0, 10));
        }
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>(list);
        TableColumn<Item, BoundedValue> amountCol = new TableColumn<>("Amount");
        amountCol.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().quantityProperty());
        amountCol.setCellFactory(tc -> createQuantityCell());
        table.getColumns().add(amountCol);
        TableColumn<Item, BoundedValue> fractionCol = new TableColumn<>("Fraction");
        fractionCol.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().quantityProperty());
        fractionCol.setCellFactory(tc -> createFractionCell());
        fractionCol.setEditable(false);
        table.getColumns().add(fractionCol);
        table.setEditable(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, turns out I can make an extra field and bind to `amount` and `max`. Although I think it's a bit ugly, it works perfectly.

I going to let this question open so maybe someone can come with a more elegant way, maybe without the extra variable.

```
public class Item {
    
    private SimpleIntegerProperty amount;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty max;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Integer[]> fraction;
    
    // I have changed the order here
    Item(int amount,int max){
        this.max = new SimpleIntegerProperty(max);
        this.amount = new SimpleIntegerProperty(amount);
        // Extra variable
        this.fraction = new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer[]>();
        this.fraction.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(()->{
            return new Integer[] {this.amount.get(),this.max.get()};
        }, this.amount,this.max));
    }
    
    public static TableView<Item> getTable(){
        TableColumn<Item,Integer[]> colAmnt = new TableColumn<Item, Integer[]>("column");
        colAmnt.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().fraction);
        // setCellFactory with fraction variable
        colAmnt.setCellFactory(d->new MaxNumberTableCell());
        colAmnt.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Item, Integer[]> t) -> {
            Item o = ((Item) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow()));
            o.amount.setValue(t.getNewValue()[0]);
        });
        
        TableView<Item> t = new TableView<Item>();
        t.getColumns().add(colAmnt);
        t.setEditable(true);
        return t;
    }
    void setFraction(int amount, int max){
        this.max.set(max);
        this.amount.set(amount);
    }
}
```

```
class MaxNumberTableCell extends TableCell<Item,Integer[]>{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Integer[] item,boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            // I can acess both values and further modify if I want
            setText(item[0]+"/"+item[1]);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```