# How to set one whole specfic column in TableVIew with data not adding data to database javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to fill one column in javafx TableView. But I don't want to add data to database SQLite because this colum should show "how many years months and days left to expire" and every day should updatde every day how many time left to expire for example: 1 year 1 month 4 days (400 days). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcV9F.png)

This is code for retriving data from this column:

```
              private void updateTimeLeft(){
                  List<String> converedDates = new ArrayList<>();
                  List<String> columnData = new ArrayList<>();

                 for (Medicaments item : ExpiryTableView.getItems()) {
                    columnData.add(String.valueOf(dateExpiry.getCellObservableValue(item).getValue()));
        
                }
                  System.out.println(columnData);
               for (String data: columnData){
                     String dateAsString = String.valueOf(data);
                     LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(inputString1, dtf);
                     LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, dtf);
                     long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);

                     int years = (int)daysBetween / 365;
                     int months = (int)(daysBetween % 365) / 30;
                     var days = (daysBetween % 365) % 30;

                     String totalTimeLeft = years+" lat "+ months+ " miesięcy "+ days + " dni "+ " ("+daysBetween+" dni)";



                      converedDates.add(totalTimeLeft);
                      System.out.println(totalTimeLeft);
                 }
```

How to set one column with converted data from function above without adding to db

Comment: Typically you would just do that in the model class. Post a [mre]

Comment: To me, it sounds like something that should be done in the cell factory. I don't think this data should be pulled separately. I think it should be pulled with the other table data as rows. This data should be represented in the model, and the calculations should be done in the cell factory.

Comment: @SedJ601 *"it sounds like something that should be done in the cell factory"*. I disagree. The cell is responsible for *how* to display the data. The model class (`Medicaments`) is responsible for providing the data to be displayed. Just because the data are derived from other data doesn't change that responsibility. The cell provided by the cell factory should only be responsible for formatting the data as text.

Comment: @James_D, That makes sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example of calculating a value in the model, as @James D points out.

The period between the Date in the DB and the current date is calculated when a Book item is created.

```
public Book(String title, String isbn, String dueDate)
{
    this.title.set(title);
    this.isbn.set(isbn);
    this.dueDate.set(LocalDate.parse(dueDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    Period period = LocalDate.now().until(this.getDueDate());        
    this.daysBeforeReturn.set(period.getDays());
}
```

### Full Code

Main

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {     
        TableColumn<Book, String> tcTitle = new TableColumn("Title");
        TableColumn<Book, String> tcIsbn = new TableColumn("ISBN");
        TableColumn<Book, LocalDate> tcDueDate = new TableColumn("Due Date");
        TableColumn<Book, Number> tcDaysBeforeReturn = new TableColumn("Days Until Due");
        tcTitle.setCellValueFactory((p) -> p.getValue().titleProperty());
        tcIsbn.setCellValueFactory((p) -> p.getValue().isbnProperty());
        tcDueDate.setCellValueFactory((p) -> p.getValue().dueDateProperty());
        tcDaysBeforeReturn.setCellValueFactory((p) -> p.getValue().daysBeforeReturnProperty());
        
        tcDaysBeforeReturn.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Book, Number> p) -> {
            return new TableCell<Book, Number>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty)
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(empty || item == null)
                    {
                        setText(null);
                        setTextFill(null);
                        setStyle("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        setText(item.toString());
                        setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                        
                        if(item.intValue() < 0)
                        {                            
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                        }
                        else if(item.intValue() == 0)
                        {                            
                           setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        
        TableView<Book> table = new TableView();
        table.getColumns().addAll(tcTitle, tcIsbn, tcDueDate, tcDaysBeforeReturn);
        DbHandler dBHandler = new DbHandler();
        ObservableList<Book> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dBHandler.getAllDbData());
        table.setItems(data);

        
        final Label label = new Label("Books");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);               
        stage.show();            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Book

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Book 
{
    private final StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty isbn = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dueDate = new SimpleObjectProperty();
    private final ObjectProperty<Number> daysBeforeReturn = new SimpleObjectProperty();
    
    public Book(String title, String isbn, String dueDate)
    {
        this.title.set(title);
        this.isbn.set(isbn);
        this.dueDate.set(LocalDate.parse(dueDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
        Period period = LocalDate.now().until(this.getDueDate());        
        this.daysBeforeReturn.set(period.getDays());
    }

    public final String getTitle()
    {
        return this.title.get();
    }
    
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title.set(title);
    }
    
    public final StringProperty titleProperty()
    {
        return this.title;
    }
    
    public final String getIsbn()
    {
        return this.isbn.get();
    }
    
    public void setIsbn(String isbn)
    {
        this.isbn.set(isbn);
    }
    
    public final StringProperty isbnProperty()
    {
        return this.isbn;
    }
    
    public final LocalDate getDueDate()
    {
        return this.dueDate.get();
    }
    
    public void setDueDate(String dueDate)
    {
        this.dueDate.set(LocalDate.parse(dueDate));
    }
    
    public final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dueDateProperty()
    {
        return this.dueDate;
    }    
    
    public Number getDaysBeforeReturn()
    {
        return this.daysBeforeReturn.get();
    }
    
    public void setDaysBeforeReturn(int daysBeforeReturn)
    {
        this.daysBeforeReturn.set(daysBeforeReturn);
    }
    
    public ObjectProperty<Number> daysBeforeReturnProperty()
    {
        return this.daysBeforeReturn;
    }
}
```

DbHandler

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class DbHandler
{
    public DbHandler()
    {
        //Connect to DB!
    }
    
    public List<Book> getAllDbData()
    {
        //Run query here!
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList();
        books.add(new Book("Until the Ends of Time", "1234567891111", "2024-01-20"));
        books.add(new Book("Hellrazor", "1234567892222", "2024-02-15"));
        books.add(new Book("Dear Mama", "123456789333", "2024-02-14"));
        books.add(new Book("Changes", "1234567894444", "2024-03-05"));
        books.add(new Book("Can't C Me", "1234567895555", "2024-01-27"));
        books.add(new Book("If I Die 2nite", "1234567897777", "2024-04-01"));
        
        return books;
    }
    
    public void close()
    {
        //Close DB!
    }
}
```

[image]