# How to compare expiry date to today date?

Tags: css, javafx, row, localdate

I'm trying to compare two dates using `LocalDate` in my `Expire` date table. The problem is that I cannot set properly row formatting according to `dateExpiry`.

This is how it should look:
[image: How to set properly cell formating]

```
if (today.isEqual(LocalDate.parse(medicament))) {
    currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:tomato");
} else if (today.before(LocalDate.parse(medicament).plusMonths(3))) {
    currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:orange");
} else {
    currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightgreen");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993400/how-to-set-one-whole-specfic-column-in-tableview-with-data-not-adding-data-to-da/77995976#77995976

Comment: it's already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

    public class ExpireDateTable {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Sample dates
            LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate dateExpiry = LocalDate.of(2024, 2, 28); //Example expiry date

            // Comparing dates and applying row formatting
            if (dateExpiry.isBefore(currentDate)) {
                System.out.println("Row formatting: Date expired, apply formatting for past expiry date.");
                // Apply formatting for past expiry date
            } else if (dateExpiry.isEqual(currentDate)) {
                System.out.println("Row formatting: Date expiring today, apply formatting accordingly.");
                // Apply formatting for expiry date today
            } else {
                System.out.println("Row formatting: Date is in the future, no special formatting needed.");
                // Apply default formatting
            }
        }
    }
```